# SPS 2013 List filter to show the latest item

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, filter

Well adding as a fresh question, as in the past have not received answer related to how to filter SharePoint list 2013 items based on latest?

any pointer will be of great help.

Comment: Currently the filters in list view gives option of either greater than or equal to, but cant find what shall I put so it pulls only the last updated item (latest) from the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution -

In the List View set the following filters:

Filters:
a) Modified - Less than or Equal to - [Today]
b) Publish Date - Less than or Equal to - [Today]
c) Publish - Begins with - Yes

Sort by Modified (Descending)

Item Limit = 1